# How to combine route path if file in sub directory express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here is my folder structure

Project

- server.js
- routes

  - auth

    - login.js
    - register.js
  - index.js

now my server.js look like this

```
const express = require("express");


const app = express();
const registerRoutes = require("./routes/auth/register");
const registerAdminRoutes = require("./routes/auth/registerAdmin");
const loginRoutes = require("./routes/auth/login");

app.use("/api-frontend", registerRoutes);
app.use("/api-backOffice", verify.isAdmin, registerAdminRoutes);
app.use("/api-backOffice/auth", loginRoutes);
```

As you seee i think it pretty dirty code If I've many route in future.
I want to required all path into index.js then I want to use something like in my `server.js`

```
app.use('/api', required(./routes))
```

Here is what I try to do

In routes/index.js I require all route

```
require("./auth/register");
require("./auth/login");
```

I'm not sure. Is their something like require 1 times and get all file in folder for make It more clean.
well after try to do something like this the error keep say in `server.js`

```
Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

Here is my example register.js

```
const express = require("express");

const registerController = require("../../controllers/register");

const router = express.Router();

router.post(
  "/register-with-social",
  registerController.validate("createUser"),
  registerController.registerWithSocial
);

module.exports = router;
```

How can I combine my routes folder In to 1 line in server.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

### routes / auth / register.js

> `router`  object will be come from `server.js` file and you can use here, and list your all routes here for this module.

```
const registerController = require("../../controllers/register");

module.exports = (router) => {

    router.post(
        "/api-frontend/register-with-social",
        registerController.validate("createUser"),
        registerController.registerWithSocial
    );
    // you can add more routes below if you want

}
```

## routes / index.js

> Load your all module'a route files here and export it.

```js
module.exports = [
    // AUTH REGISTER : ROUTES URL
    require('./auth/register'),
    // AUTH LOGIN : ROUTES URL
    require('./auth/login'),
    
    // List all your routes of auth module
];
```

**server.js**

> You can initialize all your routes from `index.js` file, load it and use it.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// just created a function, 
// if you want to use direct code then you can
// if you want to store this function in any helper library then you can
async function bootstrap(uri, modules){
    const index = require(uri);
    for (let init of index) { await init(modules); }
}
bootstrap("./routes/index", router);

app.use('/api', router);
```